# How to enter git credentials on commandline for visualstudio.com?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I try to access my git repository which is hosted on VS Team Services. Works fine in Visual Studio but I need access from the commandline using the standard git client.

When I try to do commands like pull I am asked for my credentials. Now my problem is that my credentials are my MSDN-Account data using my email and a password.

After I entered my email in the git commandline I can see it tries to build a password-url which cannot work because there are two "@"s in the address:

```
git clone https://myproject.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/coderepo
Username for 'https://myproject...':  myself@mydomain.com
Password for 'https://myself@mydomain.com@myproject...' :
```

After entering my password I receive (not surprisingly) a "fatal: Authentication failed"

So: How do I work with emails as username-credentials in git?

Comment: Unrelated: You'll be interested about [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) to avoid entering them every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution myself.

In VS Team Services, under https://[projectname]mydea.visualstudio.com/_details/security/altcreds

there can be entered "Alternate authentication credentials" with a real username (no email)

[image: alternate credentials VS Team Services]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [alternate credentials](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/overview) or [personal access token](http://roadtoalm.com/2015/07/22/using-personal-access-tokens-to-access-visual-studio-online/) to access to Team Services Hosted Git repositories.

And a more convenient way would be use [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows). This tool will prompt a Team Services sign in dialog when you need to access to Team Services Git Repository and you just need to enter your Team Services account credentials in it directly.